# Set up localhost binding on Azure cloud service

Tags: wcf, localhost, azure-web-roles

The purpose is to have a wildcard binding on the cloud service website on port 80. This is to call the WCF services locally.
I have found the solution to run some scripts at the start of the website [Running scripts from a Windows Azure role’s OnStart method](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2013/05/15/running-scripts-from-a-windows-azure-role-s-onstart-method.aspx)
When I try to implement this, the cloud services fails to start: Recycling (Waiting for role to start... System startup tasks are running.

I have added the following to my ServiceDefinition.csdef:

```
<WebRole name="ESUITE" vmsize="Small">
  <Runtime executionContext="elevated" />
  ...
  <ConfigurationSettings>
    <Setting name="RoleStartupScripts" />
  </ConfigurationSettings>
</WebRole>
```

ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg:

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="RoleStartupScripts" value="Startup\startup.cmd" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

startup.cmd:

```
powershell -command "set-executionpolicy Unrestricted"
powershell -File binding.ps1
exit
```

binding.ps1:

```
import-module WebAdministration
Get-WebSite "*ESUITE*" | Foreach-Object { 
  $site = $_;
  $siteref = "IIS:/Sites/" + $site.Name;
  New-ItemProperty $siteref -name bindings -value @{protocol="http";bindingInformation="*:80:"}
}
```

class implementing RoleEntryPoint:

```
public abstract class StartupScriptRoleEntryPoint : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        bool returnValue = false;
        try
        {
            var startupScripts = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("RoleStartupScripts");
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(startupScripts))
            {
                var scriptList = startupScripts.Split(';');
                foreach (var script in scriptList)
                {
                    bool waitForExit = false;

                    string scriptCommandLine = script;
                    if (script.EndsWith("!"))
                    {
                        scriptCommandLine = script.Substring(0, script.Length - 1);
                        waitForExit = true;
                    }

                    var args = CmdLineToArgvW.SplitArgs(scriptCommandLine);

                    var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                    {
                        FileName = args[0],
                        Arguments = string.Join(" ", args.Skip(1).ToArray()),
                        WorkingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                        UseShellExecute = true,
                    };
                    var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
                    if (waitForExit)
                    {
                        process.WaitForExit();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            returnValue = base.OnStart();
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

I can't find the issue which is causing that the website is not created / started correctly.